# Run php script in cron, with lockf addition

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I had a cronjob running every minute through crontab with the following command:

```
* * * * * lockf -k -s -t0 ~/path/to/server.php.lock curl "https://url/to/server.php"
```

However I need to avoid going through cURL, and would like to run it directly using the path using php command.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
* * * * * lockf -k -s -t0 ~/path/to/server.php.lock php ~/path/to/server.php
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Whose crontab is this? Root's? `www-data`? What's the result of running `php ~/path/to/server.php` as that user?

Comment: @amphetamachine you were right! There was a `require_once()` in server.php which was called like this: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/some_other_script.php'` which was returning a warning when ran through CLI!!! I had forgotten about that!